# C#: PowerPoint Get/Set the selected font color in ribbon

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins

I want to get/set the selected font color in PowerPoint ribbon.

[image: See Image Ribbon]

The purpose is to use:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FontColorPicker");
```

with a specific color.

Comment: If it helps I did something similar in Excel for selecting colors. https://github.com/Excel-projects/Excel-Markup

Comment: I need to know where the current font color is stored (See the image)